# Observer on sales_order_invoice_save_after

Tags: orders, event-observer, invoice

I need to execute some actions when the Order Invoice is created, so I've made an Observer and I've attached it to 'sales_order_invoice_save_after' event.

The problem is that my Observer function is called when the Invoice is made but also when Comments are added to the Invoice.

How could I check for that, so I could execute my actions only when the Invoice is made?

Comment: Have you tried calling `isObjectNew` on the invoice in the observer to determine if it is the first save before executing your logic? Not positive, but I think this should work, so you might give it a shot.

Comment: @davidalger I tried the isObjectNew on the $observer->getEvent()->getInvoice() but is false in both cases (creation and comment).

Comment: You could add a own parameter `$invoice->setData('_only_once', true)` and the second time check if it is set... Works for me every time

Comment: @Jeroen your answer saved my day, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't the most elegant of the methods but at least in my environment it works.

I've checked the content of the Event and found that there's a "data_object" with a protected field "$_comment" that is populated when you're adding a comment and empty when creating the invoice.

So I've made a check on `$observer->getEvent()->getDataObject()->getCommentsCollection()->getItems()`
to control if execute my functions or not.

Answer (score 4):

This is a somewhat older question but I ran into the same situation where I needed this. I came up with what I think is a more elegant solution by comparing the 'created at' and 'updated at' date/time stamps of the invoice. If they are the same it's a new invoice, if they aren't, it's an update.

In code:

```
$_invoice = $observer->getEvent()->getInvoice();
if ($_invoice->getUpdatedAt() == $_invoice->getCreatedAt()) {

    // Logic for new invoices

} else {

    // Logic for when invoice is updated

}
```

Hope this helps for other people needing this in the future.

Comment: I prefer this solution as is seems there is no such event like for orders `sales_order_place_after` . But I pray that createdAt and updatedAt will never differ for a second and new orders

Comment: Any idea? https://stackoverflow.com/a/65968400/3690413

Answer (score 1):

I had a giant answer on this question, and revised it to just do this:

```
if ($invoice->wasPayCalled())  {
  // Do stuff for new invoices
} else {
  // Do stuff for changes to existing invoices like comments and stuff.
}
```