# Magento 1.9 : sales_flat_order and sales_flat_order_grid tables are not updating

Tags: magento-1.9, sales-order, order-grid

I used many update methods for update values in **sales_flat_order** and **sales_flat_order_grid** tables, but no method didn't work.

I don't know why the update is not done.

Method 1:-

```
$coreResource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
$write = $coreResource->getConnection('core_write');
        $_field_flat_order =array();
        $_field_flat_order['grand_total']          = $order_gt;
        $_field_flat_order['base_grand_total']     = $order_gt;
        $_field_flat_order['discount_amount']      = $order_discount;
        $_field_flat_order['base_discount_amount'] = $order_discount;
        $_field_flat_order['discount_description'] = "1%";
        $write->update($coreResource->getTableName('sales_flat_order'),$_field_flat_order,array('entity_id = ?' => $order_id,));
```

Method 2:-

```
$order_data=Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($increment_id);
        $order_data->setGrandTotal($order_gt);
        $order_data->setBaseGrandTotal($order_gt);
        $order_data->setBaseDiscountAmount($order_discount);
        $order_data->setDiscountAmount($order_discount);
        $order_data->setDiscountDescription("1%");
        $order_data->save();
```

Method 3 :-

```
$sql_order = "UPDATE sales_flat_order SET grand_total='".$order_gt."',base_grand_total='".$order_gt."',discount_amount='".$order_discount."',base_discount_amount='".$order_discount."',discount_description='1%' WHERE entity_id ='".$order_id."'";
$write->query($sql_order);
```

No method didn't work, but all other tables are updating perfectly.

Anyone know the reason.?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<?php $write = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write'); ?>
```

And:

```
<?php
$write->query("UPDATE sales_flat_order SET grand_total = '$order_gt', base_grand_total = '$order_gt', discount_amount = '$order_discount', base_discount_amount = '$order_discount', discount_description ='1%' WHERE entity_id = '$order_id'");
?>
```

Comment: This is also not working @Marcel,I think there is a connection problem. But thank you.

Comment: Connection problem to Database? In which file you placed the Code? Have you tried the Update... direct in the database (with changed variables in orginal values) to test the query?

Comment: I am using update query in observer(sales_order_invoice_save_after) file.

Comment: If execute query directly in phpmyadmin,update is working.

Comment: Maybe this could help you: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/60288/observer-on-sales-order-invoice-save-after

Answer (score 0):

Having in mind that **"While creating invoice to particular order, We can't update sales order tables for that particular order."**, you can update that order getting it from the observer Example:

config.xml
...

```
<events>
 <sales_order_invoice_save_after>
  <observers>
   <unique_identifier>
     <type>singleton</type>
     <class>Module_SalesOrder_Model_Observer</class>
     <method>updateDeliveryDate</method>
   </unique_identifier>
  </observers>
 </sales_order_invoice_save_after>
</events>
```

...

Observer

```
class Module_SalesOrder_Model_Observer
{
   public function updateDeliveryDate(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
      $_event             = $observer->getEvent();
      $_invoice           = $_event->getInvoice();
      $_order             = $_invoice->getOrder();

      $_order->setDeliveryAt('2018-03-26 00:00:00');
      $_order->save();
   }
}
```